# How to make a simple fast and lightweight custom screen locker?

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

Day to day I'm seeing many questions which say:

- Screensaver/lock doesn't work.
- Screensaver doesn't require password after waking or doesn't lock the screen.
- Can not exit screensaver / nothing works after pressing key or moving mouse.
- and many many more not specific with gnome-screensaver only but also with xscreensaver.

So how to make a simple, fast and lightweight screensaver which locks the screen after given time and requires the password in order to continue?

In addition to my answer, I request to others who have other answer to share here.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**A tutorial to build a custom screen-lock**

1. Install two packages by executing following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xautolock xlockmore
   ```
2. Once installed enable `xlock` daemon on every time system starts by adding the entry to `Startup Applications`. Following steps will help:

   - Open Startup Applications:

   [image: image1]

   - Click <kbd>Add</kbd> button to open **Add Startup Program** window.

     Then fill with `xautolock -time 10` in **Command** text-box. It will lock the screen after every 10 minutes if the system is being idle for 10 minutes. 10 can be replaced by any natural number.  Click <kbd>Add</kbd> and then finally <kbd>Close</kbd>. Following screen will help:

   [image: image2]
   <sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1375969_464281310358430_1231560568_n.jpg))</sub>
3. That's it. A simple screen-lock is ready! :) Login and Logout to check whether it is working or not.
4. To stop the `xlock` daemon  <sub>i,e if don't want to lock the screen any more</sub> type followng command in terminal:

   ```
   xautolock -exit
   ```

   also remove the command under `Starup Applications`. Get more options and help by: `man xautolock` and `man xlock`.

**Usage**

Working can be checked by executing following command if above two packages are installed:

```
xautolock -time 1
```

If left idle for 1 minute the system will be locked. Actually the command runs the executes the `xlock` daemon which locks the system.

Feel free to edit it to make it more clear and interactive. Any types of comments and suggestions are most welcome.

Thank You!!

Comment: Why a down-vote? It is tested and working nice!! If someone get any problem, I request to post it in comment. So that I'll try to solve the problem. Some people are so mean here. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a very simple screenlocker, try slock:

http://tools.suckless.org/slock

It's a pure screen locker though, no screensaver functionality. But the code is kept very simple (just 300 LOC) so you should experience no bugs.

To launch slock automatically after a timeout, use [xautolock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xautolock) as Saurav suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Trusty has a built in screen locker that can be easily configured using the "Brightness and Lock" applet in "System Settings"